# Reverse engineer the gamma question from a typo $\int_0^1(\ln1/x)^{1/3}$dx and the answer $\Gamma(4/3)$

Tags: gamma-function

**Background**: question 9.1.2.d in a newly published book ***Mathematics for Physical Science*** by Harris.

My question is what was the question supposed to be? Taking ln(x) for ln1 I'm doing something wrong or not guessing the right typo:
$$\int_0^1(\ln(x)/x)^{1/3}\mathrm{dx}$$
$$x=e^{-u}$$
$$-\int_0^\infty (-u)^{1/3}*e^{-2u/3}(-\mathrm{du})$$
$$\int_0^\infty (-3/2u)^{1/3}*e^{-u}*(\frac{3}{2}\mathrm{du})$$

Comment: I found an error I made, let me see if I get it now... Nope, still confused.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{3}{2}\left(-3/2u\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{-u}\mathrm{du} = \int_0^\infty \frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}u^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{-u}\mathrm{du} = \\
\frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{4}{3}-1}e^{-u}\mathrm{du} =\frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right). $$

Recall also that $$\Gamma(z) = (z-1)\Gamma(z-1).$$

Then:

$$\frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) = \frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) =  \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right).$$

The results is confirmed also by [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int((log(x)%2Fx)%5E(1%2F3),x,0,1)). Actually, you can't get rid of the multiplied term in front of the final expression.

Comment: That's helpful, because it's close. I wonder if someone is clever enough to see by inspection how to get rid of the $(3/2)^{4/3}$ for instance like try $\ln(1/x)$

Comment: Oh, I agree with your answer, I meant by inspection someone can see an alternative possibility for what the question was supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you write down the *whole* process to find out mistakes? The following is what I get:

$$I:=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\log x}x\right)^{1/3}dx\;:\;\;\text{substitution}\;\;e^{-u}:=x\implies-e^{-u}du=dx\implies$$

$$I=\int_\infty^0\left(\frac{(-u)}{e^{-u}}\right)^{1/3}(-e^{-u}du)=-\int_0^\infty u^{1/3}e^{-2u/3}du$$

and now a new substitution:

$$t=\frac{2u}3\implies du=\frac32dt\implies I=-\sqrt[3]\frac32\int_0^\infty t^{1/3}e^{-t}\frac32dt=-\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac32\right)^4}\,\Gamma\left(\frac43\right)$$

Comment: I've never taken a cube root of a negative sign... Maybe the error was supposed to be s.t. different...

Comment: @user135711 First of all, you always can, both within the real numbers or the complex ones: any odd root always exists for **any** real number. Second, this is *not* what I did above, but rather $$\;u^{1/3}\to\left(\frac32t\right)^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]\frac32\,t^{1/3}\;$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the gamma function $\int_0^\infty x^{1/3}e^{-x}$dx, and making the reverse substitution ln(1/x)=u (found by solving the original substitution $e^{-u}$) yields the intended question: 
$$\int_0^1(\ln(1/x))^{1/3}\mathrm{dx}$$ with solution $\Gamma(4/3)$